# CondaVerificationError: How to install llvm-openmp package via conda on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, conda

I am trying to install the above package using conda and it fails with error message below.

```bash
conda create --name test llvm-openmp
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /home/bla/anaconda3/envs/test

  added / updated specs:
    - llvm-openmp


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    _libgcc_mutex-0.1          |      conda_forge           3 KB  conda-forge
    _openmp_mutex-4.5          |            2_gnu          23 KB  conda-forge
    libgomp-12.2.0             |      h65d4601_19         455 KB  conda-forge
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:         481 KB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  _libgcc_mutex      conda-forge/linux-64::_libgcc_mutex-0.1-conda_forge None
  _openmp_mutex      conda-forge/linux-64::_openmp_mutex-4.5-2_gnu None
  libgcc-ng          conda-forge/linux-64::libgcc-ng-12.2.0-h65d4601_19 None
  libgomp            conda-forge/linux-64::libgomp-12.2.0-h65d4601_19 None
  libzlib            conda-forge/linux-64::libzlib-1.2.13-h166bdaf_4 None
  llvm-openmp        conda-forge/linux-64::llvm-openmp-14.0.4-he0ac6c6_0 None


Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages
libgomp-12.2.0       | 455 KB    | ##################################### | 100% 
_openmp_mutex-4.5    | 23 KB     | ##################################### | 100% 
_libgcc_mutex-0.1    | 3 KB      | ##################################### | 100% 
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: failed

CondaVerificationError: The package for llvm-openmp located at /home/bla/anaconda3/pkgs/llvm-openmp-14.0.4-he0ac6c6_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/libarcher.so.bak'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.
```

I manually downloaded and unzipped the conda package once and there I could see the supposedly missing file. With version 8, for example, the installation works, but that is not enough for me. I am also sure that I had installed this package before the last Ubuntu update, then I had to reinstall the graphics driver among other things. I am using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the package is not listed in the **downloads** section of the transaction summary, implies that it is in the package cache and it is corrupted there. Try removing both the tarball (`tar.gz` and/or `.conda`) and the corresponding unbundled folder from the package cache. One can query the package cache location(s) with

```bash
conda config --show pkgs_dirs
## probably something like
## /home/bla/anaconda3/pkgs
```

and remove whatever has `llvm-openmp-14.0.4-he0ac6c6_0`.

Comment: Thanks for this advice, which actually solved my problem! I had already had such a guess, but was of the opinion that I should have solved it with the command "conda clean --all". Obviously this assumption was wrong and I was not aware that I also have to do manual deletions in this directory.